# Google API Key giving Query over limit error

Tags: google-api, google-geocoding-api, google-distancematrix-api

We have an web application which was working fine till yesterday. But since yesterday afternoon , one of our projects in google api console , all the keys started giving OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.

And we cross checked that the quotas for that project and api are still not full. Can anybody help me to understand what may have caused this.

And after a days use also the API keys are still giving the same error.

Just to give more information we are using Geocoding API and Distance Matrix API in our application.

Comment: We started seeing the same thing within the last few hours.  We were receiving a very large number of timeout errors when trying to connect to the API, then a large number of 500 errors reported in the Google API Dashboard.  Now, we're getting the error saying we exceeded the "reason"=>"rateLimitExceeded", "message"=>"Quota Error:"

It was intermittent for a while, now everything is failing.  Wondering if they are having issues with their API?  We're using the Analytics API.

Comment: How close is your usage to the daily quota?

Comment: We're back to normal now.  Our usage is very low, less than 20 API calls per min (for this use case).  100% of our requests were failing.  They are all succeeding now.

Answer (score 0):

If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code as a response.  This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more usage is allowed again. This can happen:

> Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per second.
>   Within the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The daily quotas are reset at midnight, Pacific Time.
>   This screencast provides a step-by-step explanation of proper request throttling and error handling, which is applicable to all web services.
>
> Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.

Note: It is also possible to get the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error:

1. From the Google Maps Elevation API when more than 512 points per request are provided.
2. From the Google Maps Distance Matrix API when more than 625 elements per request are provided.

Applications should ensure these limits are not reached before sending requests.

[Documentation usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

Comment: Can definitely say that Google also throws this error long before that quota is reached.  
For example Geocode quota per day is 100,000, per second is 50.
I've 30 per second, 60k per day and this error comes up in massive numbers. The console shows query rate of 30/second and a 10% error rate (due to the API throwing the wrong quota limits)

Comment: Far from perfect when it comes to their geocoding API. I've seen completely crappy results, unreliable language results typening on result type, completely wrong quota behaviour.  
People usually don't realize it but if you have a larger amount of requests (ten thousands to hundred thousands) strange things can happen.